# python, flask, and jinja2: passing parameters to url_for

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have this:

```
{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.min.css') }}
```

But I also have a timestamp in the template I would like to pass to prevent caching, like:

```
{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.min.css?timestamp=g.timestamp') }}
```

Which obviously doesn't work. The HTML needs to end up reading:

`href="css/main.min.css?timestamp= 1440133238"`

Answer (score 5):

You could use something like [this snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/40/) to override the `url_for` handler for static files.

Here's a working example:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug=True

@app.context_processor
def override_url_for():
    return dict(url_for=dated_url_for)

def dated_url_for(endpoint, **values):
    if endpoint == 'static':
        filename = values.get('filename', None)
        if filename:
            file_path = os.path.join(app.root_path,
                                     endpoint, filename)
            values['q'] = int(os.stat(file_path).st_mtime)
    return url_for(endpoint, **values)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000)
```

**templates/index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='20110307082700.jpg') }}" />
</body>
</html>
```

When the page is accessed, the following appears in the access log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Aug/2015 13:24:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Aug/2015 13:24:55] "GET /static/20110307082700.jpg?q=1422512336 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: huh, that's a little messier than I was hoping for, but certainly seems to work-- thanks!